# Extract .exe files using C#

Tags: c#, extract, unzip

This may be a simple question...I'm trying to extract or unzip exe file. I tried to unzip my exe file using winzip manually and it extracted many `.mst, .cam, .exe files in a folder cache-2012.1.2.702-win_x64` I want to do this by pro-grammatically using c#.

I got this sample code from this link:http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

Can anybodey give some code which extracts or unzip the exe file and then I want to launch a particular exe(`cache_x86.msi`) file from the extracted files.

The below makes a zip file and it's not extracting the .exe file.

```
var sfxFileToCreate = @"D:\2012.1.2.702\64\cache-2012.1.2.702-win_x64.exe";
            using (var zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                var filesToAdd = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.cs");
                zip.AddFiles(filesToAdd, "");
                var sfxOptions = new SelfExtractorSaveOptions
                {
                    Flavor = SelfExtractorFlavor.WinFormsApplication,
                    Quiet = false,
                    Copyright = "(c) 2011 Test",
                    Description = "This is a test",
                    SfxExeWindowTitle = "My SFX Window title" 
                };
                zip.SaveSelfExtractor(sfxFileToCreate, sfxOptions);
            }
```

Comment: Can you clarify a few points? Are you trying to extract any 'exe' or just SFX files? If it is the SFX, which tool was used to generate it. Is it dotnetzip only?

Comment: @ Amit Mittal: I'm trying to extract a exe file. I would like to use any tool which'll allow me to extract the exe file to install another exe file from the extracted one.

Comment: Simplistically speaking, not all exe files contain other files. Solution to extract required files will depend on the nature of the exe file you have. For instance if the required file is a SFX archive created through dotnetzip, it will itself be an archive that can be extracted using dotnetzip, 7zip etc. Some other exe files may not be an archive file at all and may simply embed a file in their resource stream (but remember not all exe files embed other files). So if you can include this detail in the question, it will aid in answering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to use 7zip.exe console app. You can start it using Process class.

[edit]

Here's the tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Comment: @linguini, this sounds a bit like `gimme the codez` request, don't you think? Did you try implementing it yourself? Did you encounter some specific problems with your implementation?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I'm not asking for the entire code, I couldn't find something. The code I'm using it makes a zip file. I want to extract the exe file to install an another exe file from the extracted file.

Answer (score 1):

```
    output = StartProcessing("MySelfExtractExeFile.exe", " /auto " + sOutputFilePath);

    private string StartProcessing(string sProcessingFile, string Arguments)
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = sProcessingFile;// "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;// " /auto " + sOutputFilePath;

            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //make the window Hidden 
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ex            
        }
    }
```